# How to configure 'entities' for a 'reusable bundle' in Symfony 4.x?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm on symfony 4.x, I created a reusable bundle for an easyadmin add-on. I create an entity that is well known but when submitting data, I have a method _prePersist for HasLifecycleCallbacks that is not detected.

```
/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{}
```

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function _prePersist()
{
  dump($this);die;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. How do you persist the object? Where is this PrePersist-Hook and when is it supposed to be triggered and how? For example is this a Doctrine-event or is it supposed to hook into EasyAdmin-Bundle's event (see https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Controller/AdminControllerTrait.php#L283)? Have you checked with `bin/console debug:events` whether the event is registered correctly?

Comment: Ok when creating a post, I have a slug field which I would like to automatically manage in a method in the entity using lifecycles events. I always do this and its always walking but when I move my code from the src / to lib / acmebundle folder it does not work anymore. And since the slug field is required, the validation of the form fails.
in src / Entity, it works and in lib / AcmeBundle / Entity, it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to update your Bundle's configuration to register both the folder where you keep your entities and probably the lifecycle events as well. When placing them in `src/Entity` this is not necessary, because the [DoctrineBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/tree/master/DependencyInjection) already provides default configuration for that. This is why in your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` you have the following:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

You should track how the DoctrineBundle reads & processes this configuration from the [Configuration.php](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L413) and then how the Service Container is configured from these config values by looking at [DoctrineExtension.php](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L549). You can probably omit the Configuration file, but your `MyBundleExtension` needs to update the Doctrine-services with your entity classes from inside the bundle.

Alternatively you can look at Recipes and instead of keeping the Entity in your bundle copy it into the src/ directory whenever your bundle is installed. Due to how recipes work, your bundle will need to be open source for this and you will have to provide a [contrib-recipe for this bundle](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib).

edit: Another option could be to provide a full skeleton for your basic setup, so that you don't need to worry about bundles and independent configuration and instead just provide a basic starter application with a default setup you deem useful.

Comment: Can you give me a little demo example for solution 1 and 3?

Comment: As for solution 3 you can take [symfony/demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo) as an example. Just create as small an application as you think fits your idea of a "project skeleton", create a Github-repo and then either provide a package via packagist, like [symfony/symfony-demo](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony-demo) and then you can build new projects from this skeleton as described in the docs with `composer create-project ...`. If you don't want to create a project it's a bit trickier (see: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2920#issuecomment-190303745)

Comment: As for solution 1, it will take some work and I don't think I can adequately explain it without spending too much time on it. I suggest looking at both linked files as a foundation and the Symfony docs for [Extensions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html) and [Bundle configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html)